# Data-node Alive from ambari isnt stable

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, namenode, datanode

we have ambari cluster version - 2.6.1 and hadoop version 2.6.4

number of datanode are - 10

from ambari dashboard we can see the window that show the follwing:

```
   DataNodes Live

   9/10
```

but after few min all datanode are alive as:

```
   DataNodes Live

   10/10
```

and again after few min we see again

```
   DataNodes Live

   9/10
```

its seems that namenode has not received heartbeat msg from a datanode for more than  interval, then datanode will be marked and  as "dead"

we check the follwing:

1. host resolution are - OK ( DNS is OK )
2. IP's resolution are - ok  ( DNS is OK )
3. HDFS service check is passed successfully
4. each datanode is up (  ps -ef | grep datanode | grep -v grep )
5. netstat -anp | grep '0.0.0.0:50010' port is ok
6. systemctl status firewalld.service ( firewall is down as should be )
7. sestatus SELinux status ( is disable )
8. MTU is configured to 9000 ( and we verify that 9000 set correctly on all component

**what we can do else in order to verify why DataNode alive isn't stable ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we increased the data node heap size from default value - 2G to 6G
since then , now data node alive from ambari dashboard are stable